# Need to get dates between two date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two date columns, 
effdate and enddate and need to get a list of dates between two dates in third column.

for example,

```
effdate      | enddate
2012-09-01   |2019-06-11
2012-10-02   |2012-08-31
```

I want to get list dates between these two dates as a third column

Comment: Can you put an example of the table which you want to get the data from please? If is the case just do it: `select * from [your table] where [date column] between effdate and enddate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE is a pretty easy method:

```
with dates as (
      select effdate as dte, enddate
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), enddate
      from dates
      where dte < enddate
     )
select dte
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Often a tally table has somewhat better performance:

```
with digits as (
      select v.n
      from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(n)
     ),
     n as (
      select (d1*1000 + d2*100 + d3*10 + d4*1) n
      from digits d1 cross join
           digits d2 cross join
           digits d3 cross join
           digits d4 
     )
select dateadd(day, n.n, t.effdate)
from t join
     n
     on dateadd(day, n.n, t.effdate) <= t.enddate  ;
```

You have to be sure that your table of numbers -- however generated -- is big enough for your timespan.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for get your desired list of dates-

```
DECLARE @D1 DATETIME = '20190601'
DECLARE @D2 DATETIME = '20190611'
DECLARE @LoopCount INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DD,@D1,@D2))

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    date date
)

WHILE @LoopCount >= 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable (date)
    VALUES (DATEADD(DD,-@LoopCount,GETDATE()))

    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount - 1
END

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```